# How to fetch last login datetime using PHP and MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have 4-5 login record but I want to fetch last login date and time from MySQL database. ex: my last login datetime is 2017-02-03. then how to show or fetch this record from database.login is my field and it's field type is datetime.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result. If it is overall latest, you could use `max(datetimefield)`.

Comment: show some code here

Comment: <?php $date1 = date("Y:m:d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 days"));
echo $date1;
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
{
 //  for display login time show  
 echo"</br>";
$sql1="select * from attendence where eid=".$_SESSION["eid"]."and login='".$date1."'";
$result=$conn->query($sql1);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
  echo "<tr><td>".$row["login"]."<br>";       
 }
 echo "</table>";
}
else 
{
 echo "  0 results";
}
$conn->close();
}
?>

Comment: In the question please and in the form of **formatted text**

Comment: Please give your tried code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it using SQL query. The following is the query you might be looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM login_history WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY login_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This is just an example what the query looks like. You can modify it according to the column names you have in the table.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi sir, I have one more question. I am trying to insert logout date and time in MySQL using PHP. but 2 submit button is there and each button performs a different action on different pages.  in this case, i want to only store current date and time in logout column in database .

Comment: Add `login_date_time` and `logout_date_time` columns in the table to track the login and logout time. Basically, `logout_date_time` should allow `NULL` by default. This is where you will start to get into action. Insert a row with all the columns filled with corresponding data except `logout_date_time` which will be updated when you log out. This is a basic idea how login history in a web application works. When you login, you will be adding the row in the `login_history` table with `logout_date_time` alone blank. Store the `ID` of that row in the session.

Comment: This `ID` will later be referenced to update the row when logging out. When you perform logout operation, reference this `ID` in the session to update the row. Here, you will be updating `logout_date_time` with the current date and time. There might be any numbers of ways to do this efficiently. But the one I suggested you seems to be the simpler. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've made an answer for your question posted in the comment. Since this involves a big answer, I can't make it into a single comment. So, posted it into two comments.